# Pipeline with PolynomialFeatures and LinearRegression - unexpected result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, pipeline

with the following code I just want to fit a regression curve to sample data which is not working as expected.

```
X = 10*np.random.rand(100)
y= 2*X**2+3*X-5+3*np.random.rand(100)
xfit=np.linspace(0,10,100)


poly_model=make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(2),LinearRegression())
poly_model.fit(X[:,np.newaxis],y)


y_pred=poly_model.predict(X[:,np.newaxis])


plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Shouldnt't there be a curve which is perfectly fitting to the data points? Because the training data (X[:,np.newaxis]) and the data which get used to predict y_pred are the same (also (X[:,np.newaxis]).

If I instead use the xfit data to predict the model the result is as desired...

```
...

y_pred=poly_model.predict(xfit[:,np.newaxis])

plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(xfit[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")

plt.show()
```

[image]

So whats the issue and the explanation for such a behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two plots is that in the line

```
plt.plot(X[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")
```

The values in `X[:,np.newaxis]` are not sorted, while in

```
plt.plot(xfit[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")
```

the values of `xfit[:,np.newaxis]` are sorted.

Now, `plt.plot` connects any two consecutive values in the array by line, and since they are not sorted you get this bunch of lines in your first figure.

Replace

```
plt.plot(X[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")
```

with

```
plt.scatter(X[:,np.newaxis],y_pred,color="red")
```

and you'll get this nice looking figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Miriam Farber I have figured out an other way. Since the X values are not sorted I can fix the issue by simply sort the values with:

```
X=np.sort(X)
```

Now the remaining code can remain stationary and will deliver the desired result.

[image]